# Difficult product problem $\prod \limits^{2014}_{k=1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{k^{2}} \right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, products

Evaluate the product
$$\prod \limits^{2014}_{k=1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{k^{2}} \right)$$

Any help will appreciated!

Comment: assuming k starts from 2... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265483/evaluating-the-infinite-product-prod-k-2-infty-left-1-frac1k2-r?lq=1

Answer (score -1):

The answer is $0$, since when $k=1$, $1-\frac{1}{k^2}=0$.